# How to find minimum value every x values in an array?

Tags: python, numpy, minimum

```
path = ("C:/Users/Calum/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35-32/Python Programs/PV Data/Monthly Data/brunel-11-2016.csv")
with open (path) as f:
    readCSV = csv.reader((islice(f, 0, 8352)), delimiter = ';')
    irrad_bru1 = []

    for row in readCSV:
         irrad1 = row[1]

         irrad_bru1.append(irrad1)

irrad_bru1 = ['0' if float(x)<0 else x for x in irrad_bru1]
bru_arr1 = np.asarray(irrad_bru1).astype(np.float)

rr_bru1 = -np.diff(bru_arr1)
```

I want to find the minimum value in the array rr_bru1 every 200 entries how do I go about doing that?

Comment: List slicing in ranges of 200 sounds straightforward to me

Comment: how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.minimum.reduceat`:

```
np.minimum.reduceat(a, np.arange(0, len(a), 200))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it using slicing:

Python 3

```
n = 200
[min(mylist[i:i + n]) for i in range(0, len(mylist), n)]
```

Python 2

```
n = 200
[min(mylist[i:i + n]) for i in xrange(0, len(mylist), n)]
```